Prove stability of solution to a system of differential equations
How to prove that the zero solution of the following system of differential equations is stable, but not asymptotically stable?
\begin{cases}\dot{x} = y - y^2 \\\dot{y} = -x\end{cases}
It is easy to see that its phase portraits are given by the equation
$$x^2 + y^2 -\frac{2}{3}y^3 = C$$
If we plot this, we can see that for very small positive values of $C$ there are small cycles near the center of the coordinates. Which hints at the fact which we are trying to prove. However, it is not clear how to adequately plot them without a computer program and how to prove stability rigorously.

If $x^2+y^2-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3=C$, it follows that $||(x,y)||^2=x^2+y^2=C+\dfrac{2}{3}y^3$, and that $y^2-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3\leq C$.
Notice that $g(y)=y^2-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3$ is a strictly increasing function on $[0,1]$, as $g'(y)=2y-2y^2>0$.
This means that the inverse of $g$ exists and is increasing too.
Take $\delta>0$ (sufficiently small so it is on the image of $g$).
If  $x^2+y^2-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3=\delta$ then $g(y)=y^2-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3\leq \delta$ and consequently $y=g^{-1}(g(y))\leq g^{-1}(\delta)$.
From here, $||(x,y)||^2=\delta+\dfrac{2}{3}y^3\leq\delta+\dfrac{2}{3}g^{-1}(\delta)^3$.
Given $\epsilon>0$, as $g^{-1}$ is continuous at $0$ we may choose $\delta$ such that $\delta<\epsilon/2$ and $\dfrac{2}{3}g^{-1}(\delta)^3<\epsilon/2$, proving that $||(x,y)||^2<\epsilon$ and thus the stability.
Regarding asymptotic stability, we can use that the orbit associated to every point different from the origin will be of the form $x^2+y^2-\dfrac{2}{3}y^3=C, C>0$. This a compact set so $||(x,y)||$ attains its minimum at it. This minimum cannot be $0$ as the origin does not belong to this curve, so we will have $||(x,y)||>c$ for some $c>0$, implying that the solution cannot converge to the origin.

Aren't we assuming that y>0? What if it's less than 0?

@ElectroSchOOp If $y<0$ then $x^2+y^2=\delta+\dfrac{2}{3}y^3<\delta$. As $\delta<\epsilon/2$ this also works.
